# Finding the area of a region by a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

$$ \int \int_D (1-y) dxdy $$

$$ x^2+y^2 \leq 2y $$

$$ y \leq x^2 $$

$$ x \geq 0 $$

[picture of functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAlor.png)

[The area of a region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg3is.png)

I have this exercise and I do not know how to solve it. I have to find the Domain for the x and the y coordinates. In the picture I can see a circle that is placed under a parabola and it is cutted in half vertically. 
Do you have to use polar coordinates?
My region is the second picture.

Comment: You don't need polar coordinates. Everything here is polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 + y^2 = 2y$ can be written as $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$ $\implies $ $y = 1 \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

The parabola intersects the circle at $(0,0)$ and $( 1,1)$ in the right half plane.

so you can write \begin{align*}
\int_D (1 - y) dy dx &= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}^{x^2} (1 - y) dy \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{2} x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x^4 \right) dx\\
&= \frac{1}{15}
\end{align*}